# PDF.js Native Android Browser Issue

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, canvas

I've been tasked with finding a way to display PDFs in Android browsers without having to download them to the users' phones. So far, I've found PDF.js to be very well suited for this. It works on every other phone/browser I've tried except for Android's native browser (it works fine in Chrome on the same exact phone). I've tried it on 2 Androids (4.1.2 and 4.3.x) and it doesn't work on either.

[Examples of what is happening here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYRvK.jpg) (the red boxes are absolute divs elements derived from PDF metadata. They are not part of the canvas. I know that its loading the document, just not rendering it).

[My whole code is located here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Javadocs/myTM3/1/)

```
PDFJS
    .getDocument(PDFSource)
    .then(function(pdf) {
        //make canvas for each page
        for(var i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {

            //add an annotation div and a canvas to draw to.
            $('body').append('<div id="AnnotationLayer' + i + '" class="annotations"></div><canvas id="PDFCanvas' + i + '"></canvas>');

            //get the page
            pdf.getPage(i).then(function(page) {
                var scale = 1;
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                var scaledViewport = viewport;

                var canvas = document.getElementById('PDFCanvas' + page.pageNumber);
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = scaledViewport.height;
                canvas.width = scaledViewport.width;

                var renderContext = {
                  canvasContext: context,
                  viewport: scaledViewport
                };

                //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //tried this
                page.render(renderContext);
                //canvas.width = canvas.width; //tried this

                //tried commenting out annotations, did not seem to work
                var $annotationLayerDiv = $('#AnnotationLayer' + page.pageNumber);

                //extract links from the page and put them absolutely positioned over the canvas
                annotations(page, canvas, $annotationLayerDiv);
            })
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is. There is no errors that come up. It seems like its a canvas issue but I've tried the hacks I've found googling, but none of them have worked. The document doesn't even show up (no flickering or anything). It just doesn't load.

Does anyone see anything that could cause this code not to work in Android's native browser? Is there something up with the canvas element on Android's browser?